# Windows 10 Penetration Testing

Tags: penetration-test, windows-10

I've done my CEH and ecsa certifications, I'm doing CISSP and sec560 this year also, so I know the basics of penetration testing but I want to expand my knowledge.

CEH/ECSA don't cover pen testing windows 10, they focus on XP and windows 7. 
Are there any reliable sources/guides on exploitable vulnerabilities on windows 10? Essentially I want to make the jump from basic penetration testing to a more advanced level.

Comment: it appears that you are not looking for 'pen testing', you are looking for vulnerabilities with known exploits

Comment: if you want to know how to find your own vulnerabilities, that's another topic entirely

Comment: @schroeder have edited the question.

Comment: @schroeder yes I'm looking for both, I'd like to find my own vulnerabilities - however I feel that this may be slightly above my level, I'm willing to give it a try regardless

Comment: Then your question is too broad. How to find new vulnerabilities is a process that is not confined to any OS version or model. There are numerous tutorials. As for lists of Win10 vulnerabilities, there are also numerous databases and tutorials for those, too.